# Problems making shortcode with custom post types and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, shortcode, taxonomy

I have a custom post type *work-gallery* and a custom taxonomy *use* which serves to categorize the posts.

I am trying to develop a shortcode which enables me to output the work-gallery posts that belong to a particular use.I suppose it would be the equivalent of a category archive query except that I want to be able to use it on different pages.

The code looks like this:

```
function wg_album($wguse){ 
extract(shortcode_atts(
    array('use' => 'work'), $wguse)); 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'work-gallery',
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'use',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $use
                )
            )
        );
$work_galleries = new WP_Query($args);
ob_start(); ?>
    <ul class="work-pages">
<?php foreach ($work_galleries as $work_gallery) { ?>       
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $work_gallery -> ID ); //the permalink?>">

                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($work_gallery -> ID)//the featured image?>
                <h3><?php echo $work_gallery -> post_title ; ?></h3>

            <p> <?php echo $work_gallery -> post_excerpt ; ?></p>
            </a>
        </li>

<?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php return ob_get_clean(); 
} ?>
```

What I get, instead of output of the permalink, title, featured image and excerpt - as in the code - is the permalink of the host page, iterated 40 times!

What am I doing wrong ? The problem, I think is in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very broken Loop. The results of a new `WP_Query` is not a simple array that you can `foreach` over. It is far more complicated than that. Try `var_dump($work_galleries);`.

Fortunately, `WP_Query` provides methods to make looping easy.

```
$work_galleries = new WP_Query($args);
if ($work_galleries->have_posts()) {
  while ($work_galleries->have_posts()) { // this replaces foreach
    $work_galleries->the_post(); // this sets up the post data so functions like the_title() work
    // now your code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a speedy reply that works !! get_posts() uses a foreach loop, doesn't it ? What is the difference from WP_Query and which is better ? Before I moved the galleries to a custom post type I used get_pages(), that's why I used a foreach...

Comment: [`get_posts` uses `WP_Query` internally](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1672) and just returns the actual array of results. I rarely use anything but `WP_Query` but whether that is "better" is a judgement call.